# How to test output HTTP request content in Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, spring-mvc

I have the Spring application.

We have the service which makes HTTP requests to external services. Now I think about writing Unit Test on this functionality. I want to write the integration tests. Thus I want to know that service request is correct.

Is there ways to do it in spring? (actually I don't know ways to do it outside the Spring too)

Comment: You want to validate your request or the response from the external service?

Comment: @slowy  I want to validate request first of all. Also it will be nice to have tool to imitate responce

Comment: I'd do something like Service calls RequestService, RequestService calls external Service. So you can write tests Unit tests for Service, Integration test für RequestService. You can do that with spring, @see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html... but I prefer apache http client :P

Comment: @slowy, I want to test service which written using restTemplate

Answer (score 0):

In tests you can use some kind of mock server. [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/) for example.

Wiremock can work as a proxy and log all your requests and responses. More than that - it can then save responses and use them as stubs. It can be very useful to test integration problems with number of fault simulations.

For spring boot there is a starter:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epages</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.18</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

More documentation available here: https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-wiremock

Then create a test and setup a [proxy](http://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {
            YourApplication.class,
    }
)
@WireMockTest // it comes from starter
public class YourTest {

    @Inject
    private WireMockServer server;

    @Value("http://localhost:${wiremock.port}")
    private String uri;


    @Test
    public void shouldLogAllTheThings() throws Exception {
       server.stubFor(get(urlMatching("/other/service/.*"))
           .willReturn(
                aResponse()
                    .proxiedFrom("http://otherhost.com/approot")
       ));

       // your call with rest template using uri field value
       // as base uri
    }


    @TestConfiguration
    public static class Internal {

        @Inject
        public WireMockConfiguration configuration;

        @PostConstruct
        public void wiremock() {
            // this adds verbosive logger 
            // which will print all communication
            configuration.notifier(new Slf4jNotifier(true));
        }
    }
}
```

More info: 
http://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/

Mappings can be saved using this doc: http://wiremock.org/docs/record-playback/

If you don't want to use starter, you can use wiremock as JUnit rule:
http://wiremock.org/docs/junit-rule/